# Image does not display in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, image, html5-canvas, png

I want to load a png image in base64 to html5 canvas element. I have this code:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="pageCanvas"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var canvas = document.getElementById("pageCanvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var imageData ="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAIAAAACDbGyAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9oMCRUiMrIBQVkAAAAZdEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBXgQ4XAAAADElEQVQI12NgoC4AAABQAAEiE+h1AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.src = imageData;
            ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 50, 100);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above code working well in IE, chrome, Microsoft edge. But in Firefox the image was not displayed. It display blank page. Sometime when we reload the page then it displayed an image in canvas.

Thank you very much for the answers.

Comment: Do you see any javascript errors in the console ?

Comment: Yeah, agreed to faheem. Check your console for errors. I currently don't have firefox but your code works on my IE and chrome

Comment: thank you for your guidelines. I checked the console it does not show any error related to image rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is bad :

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = imageData;
ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 50, 100);
```

You should wait image load :

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function(){
   ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 50, 100);
}
imageObj.src = imageData;
```

If you don't need callback, you can wait image complete == true, but i am not advice to use this code

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = imageData;
while(!imageObj.complete){/**thread sleep wile image is not ready**/}
ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 50, 100);
```

Comment: when we using image onload to render the image content in html5 canvas. It should display on time of Page onload, so it make some delay to display. Also if we render shapes or text above the image means, first render the shapes then render the image finally. It hide the text or shapes.

Comment: You can't do this without image load! If it will work, it will work unstable, depends of image size.It will work only with luck.Unstable.

Comment: The above script  to render the image without any issue in IE, Chrome, Microsoft Edge browser. But in Firefox have the issue to display a image..

Comment: Is big luck that is worked.It is worked because you image is not very big,browsers have different engines, and do the load and render tasks differently.That is mean that browsers have different time to load and render.One browser will work with your cod good, but other will not work.If you will have callback.All browsers will execute your code properly.